# How to set the date regardless of timezones?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, date, datetime

I need to query the records based on its created dates. Say for example, I have to query the records created between two dates `2012-03-01 00:00:00` to `2012-03-03 23:59:00`. I use times in my query like

```
$from_date = '01/03/2012';
$to_date = '03/03/2012';
$from = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($from_date));
$to = date('Y-m-d 23:59:00', strtotime($to_date));
```

The query works fine in localhost, since I have my database in my country. But it doesn't work fine in live site. Since, time zone differs, automatically the date created changes to

```
$from = 2012-03-01 17:00:00
$to = 2012-03-03 16:59:00
```

ie., it changes to its time zone. I tried converting date to that timezone. But it didn't work. Now, what can I do to give correct time for the query?

Answer (score 2):

You should call [`date_default_timezone_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) prior to calling the `date(...)` methods.

It's worth noting that since PHP 5.1.0, every call to a date/time function will generate a E_NOTICE if the timezone isn't valid, and/or a E_WARNING message if using the system settings or the TZ environment variable, so it's worth looking at your errors...

Comment: Or just set in your server configuration if its possible!

Comment: Good point @Michael - the linked doc does mention setting [`date.timezone`](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) in the ini file

Comment: I agree with @RowlandShaw you should call `date_default_timezone_set()` before `date()`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need to do

```
$from_date = '01/03/2012';
$to_date = '03/03/2012';
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($from_date." 00:00:00"));
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($to_date." 23:59:00"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers above are correct, but I'd like to give you different point of view at your problem. Since you are interested only in proper daysn not hours then you can use your dates `$from_date` and `$to_date` by formating dates stored in db directly in sql query like this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(column_with_date,'%d/%m/%Y')
```